# (C#) Google Cloud Task - UNKNOWN response status for HTTP request to Cloud Run service

Tags: c#, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-tasks

UPDATE

Host name gerenarates with little difference from Google Doc.
not https://SERVICE_IDENTIFIER.run.app
but https://SERVICE_IDENTIFIER.a.run.app

Question is closed

---

I have Cloud Run service. It works fine.
I have class that create tasks in Cloud Task. It works fine too, all HTTP tasks with request to external web resourses executed.

But when I create HTTP task with request to Cloud Run service, task has created and then return **UNKNOWN** response status while dispatching. In the Log I see, that task has run (failed), but Cloud Run service has`t received any requests.

When I create request manualy (with the same payload to the same url) - it works.

What i do wrong?

**Credentials / Secure:**

- Cloud Run srvice in public access
- Cloud Run service launched and Cloud Task created with the same Service Account
- Service Account roles:

  - Cloud Datastore User
  - Cloud Run Invoker
  - Cloud Run Service Agent
  - Cloud Tasks Enqueuer
  - Cloud Tasks Service Agent
  - Service Account OpenID Connect Identity Token Creator
  - Service Account User

**There is code to create Cloud Task:**

```cs
protected async Task CreateTaskAsync(
    Uri uri, // URI to my Cloud Run service in format https://SERVICE_IDENTIFIER.run.app/my/path
    DateTime runDate,
    string payload, // JSON data
    HttpMethod method = HttpMethod.Post
)
{
    var task = new Google.Cloud.Tasks.V2.Task {
        HttpRequest = new HttpRequest {
            HttpMethod = method,
            Url = uri.ToString(),
            Body = ByteString.CopyFromUtf8(payload),
            Headers = { { "Content-Type", "application/json" } },
            // After googling I try to add OIDC token, but it does not help
            OidcToken = new OidcToken
            {
                ServiceAccountEmail = Constants.ServiceConfiguration.ServiceAccount ,
                Audience = Constants.ServiceConfiguration.Host
            }
        },
        ScheduleTime = Timestamp.FromDateTime(runDate),
    };
    
    
    var projectId = Constants.ServiceConfiguration.ProjectId;
    _queueName = new QueueName(projectId, Location, BotQueueName);

    _tasksClient = CloudTasksClient.Create();
    await _tasksClient.CreateTaskAsync(_queueName, task);
}
```

**There is Log for Cloud Task:**

```json
{
  "insertId": $INSERT_ID$,
  "jsonPayload": {
    "task": $TASK_NAME$,
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.tasks.logging.v1.TaskActivityLog",
    "taskCreationLog": {
      "targetType": "HTTP",
      "status": "OK",
      "scheduleTime": "2022-11-21T07:00:00Z",
      "targetAddress": "POST https://SERVICE_IDENTIFIER.run.app/my/path"
    }
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_tasks_queue",
    "labels": { ... }
  },
  "timestamp": "2022-11-20T22:27:09.397470874Z",
  "severity": "INFO",
  "logName": $LOG_NAME$,
  "receiveTimestamp": "2022-11-20T22:27:10.010639079Z"
},
{
  "insertId": $INSERT_ID$,
  "jsonPayload": {
    "attemptResponseLog": {
      "maxAttempts": 0,
      "attemptDuration": "0.031349s",
      "status": "UNKNOWN",
      "responseCount": "0",
      "targetAddress": "POST https://SERVICE_IDENTIFIER.run.app/my/path",
      "targetType": "HTTP",
      "dispatchCount": "1",
      "scheduleTime": "2022-11-21T07:00:00Z"
    },
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.tasks.logging.v1.TaskActivityLog",
    "task": $TASK_NAME$
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_tasks_queue",
    "labels": { ... }
  },
  "timestamp": "2022-11-20T22:33:10.367512625Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "logName": $LOG_NAME$,
  "receiveTimestamp": "2022-11-20T22:33:11.022774614Z"
}
```

I try add role to the Service Account, try add OIDC token to the task, try send requrst with diferent HTTP methods - nothing help.

Creating task with the same payload to the different url (external web resource) works fine.

Comment: It appears from the log that the Cloud Task is running OK. Your Cloud Run service instance is failing. Add logging for your instance to know more about the problem.

Comment: @JohnHanley First log record is about creating task and it's OK - task have created. Second record - run task, and it have failed ("severity": "ERROR").
Cloud Run service instance does not have log record, because Could Task does not send request to it.

Comment: OMG, It is so stupid(((
Host name gerenarates with little difference from Google Doc.
Not https://SERVICE_IDENTIFIER.run.app,
but https://SERVICE_IDENTIFIER.a.run.app. I close my question